# Is it possible to exclude words when ordering posts alphabetically?

Tags: alphabetical, args

I have my `args` set up like:

```
'order'             => 'ASC',
'orderby'           => 'title',
```

My posts are alphabetized, but here's now they look, these are real posts names and they're medical, just saying before you think I'm sort of weirdo.

```
Discharge Instructions for a GreenLight Laser Prostatectomy
Discharge Instructions for Adult Circumcision
```

I need to exclude "a" so that "Adult Circumcision" goes first. Is this possible?

Comment: With what language? What are the rules of the text you want to exclude? Only the work "a"?

Comment: ah I realized i didn't mention I was in `php` and WordPress. I'll update the OP.